# Why do you need inclusion guard for C++ header files?

Tags: c++, header-files

I get roughly what it does.  What I don't understand is why it's not the default?  What are the use cases where some header file would need to be included multiple times?

Comment: suggest changing title to use phrase "inclusion guard" rather than "pragma once", since the latter is a way of doing the former in a platform specific manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it's not the default is primarily historical these days -- when the C language was formalized, `#include` was specified that it must act exactly as if the user had copy-and-pasted the specified file's contents at the location of the `#include`-line; and C++ wanted (and wants) to remain as compatible as possible with C, so C++ inherited that behavior from C.

As for a use-case where including the same header file more than once might be useful; one instance where I found it useful was for simulating a templated-container-class in C (because C doesn't support templates directly).  I had a container-implementation-header-file that looked something like this (but more elaborate; I'm showing a simplified version here for readability):

```
// MyContainerImplemention.h
// be sure to #define MYTYPE and MYARRAYSIZE
// before #include-ing this file!

struct ArrayOf##MYTYPE
{
   MYTYPE arrayOfItems[MYARRAYSIZE];
};

inline void Set##MYTYPE##Item(struct ArrayOf##MyType * container, int which, MYTYPE item) 
{
   container[which] = item;
}

[... and so on for various other MYTYPE-specific methods ...]
```

... then my .c files could do something like:

```
#define MYTYPE int
#define MYARRAYSIZE 10
#include "MyContainerImplementation.h"
#undef MYARRAYSIZE
#undef MYTYPE

#define MYTYPE short
#define MYARRAYSIZE 15
#include "MyContainerImplementation.h"
#undef MYARRAYSIZE
#undef MYTYPE

struct ArrayOfint myInts;
struct ArrayOfshort myShorts;

SetintItem(&myInts, 5, 12);
SetshortItem(&myShorts, 3, 2);
[...]
```

... and end up with the container "class" and its associated methods implemented for each data-type, without having to manually write a new implementation of the container "class" each time.

Yes, it was extremely ugly -- but not as ugly as having to manually write out thousands of lines of redundant container-code would have been.  (The real container-implementation-header-file implemented a hash table and was several hundred lines long)

Answer (score 4):

Without include guards or #pragma once the compiler would have to maintain a list of included files. This is not easy, because of different possible paths to these files (and #pragma once doesn't completely solve this) and would be expecting a bit much of the original C compilers, which had to work with very limited memory.

Answer (score 2):

What's true today is not necessarily true when C came about and the C pre-processor, upon which the C++ one is based, was created.

`#pragma once` is just a step towards having proper [C++ modules](https://medium.com/@wrongway4you/brief-article-on-c-modules-f58287a6c64) so this annoying historical legacy is finally eliminated.

Yes, it's valid to include a file multiple times, and yes, each time it's included it can behave in entirely different ways. This is why making pre-compiled headers is a huge headache for compiler developers.

Answer (score 2):

Guard blocks or `#pragma once` are included in order to prevent a file from being included multiple times.

`#pragma once`, while supported on most compilers, is not an official part of the c++ standard, and may not work on every compiler. You can use a guard block, which will work on any compiler. An example of a guard block in the file `MyClass.hpp` would be:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_HPP
#define MYCLASS_HPP

//Code here

#endif
```

Comment: While you make a good point, this doesn't actually answer the question that was posed. Consider adding a paragraph explaining why `#pragma once` *or* include guards are necessary.

Comment: Also worth noting a large degree of uniqueness is required in the identifier used in the `#ifndef`. The other day we had a question where some poor soul used the name of the class in the header resulting in the class name being macro substituted with an empty string. `#define myclass` and then later `class myclass { ... };` resulted in utter chaos as the compiler saw `class  { ... };`.